# What problem can solve with reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I think classification problem cannot solve with reinforcement learning. I don't know what problem can solve with reinforcement learning. Is there a way to see if this problem can be solved with reinforcement learning?

Comment: [Using Reinforcement Learning for Classfication Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44594007/14045537)

Answer (score 0):

**Reinforcement Learning**:
Agents make a sequence of decisions through reward/penalty for the action performed

To answer your question ***yes*** RL can be used for classification

Though reinforcement learning can be utilized to solve classification problems it is not recommended.

- Reinforcement Learning takes long time to train
- Accuracy of Supervised Classification `>` Accuracy of Reinforcement Learning

This paper can help you get started on the [Reinforcement learning algorithms](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5967372?reload=true) that can be used for solving classification problems

Video explanation of why not to go for [RL for classification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=td0TjL5tznc)